# extract text from txt a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a a file containing about 20 million sentences, how can I extract 2 million sentences out from it? 
I thought about using the split command like this "split -l 2000000 sub2016", but then it will create a series of texts, while I just need one. 
So how can I specify it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first two million lines:

```
head -n 2000000 sub2016
```

If you want a block of two million lines taken at random within the file:

```
tail -n +$((RANDOM * RANDOM % 18000000)) sub2016 | head -n 2000000
```

This picks two random numbers between 0 and 32767, multiplies them, reduces the range to 18 million (20 million minus 2 million), skips that many lines and outputs two million lines.

Comment: Thank you! I just need the first two million lines. It worked. By the way, if I want to extract 2 million words, how should i specify then?